# Is there a c++ bind can cross v8 and JavaScriptCore?

Tags: c++, v8, javascriptcore

Im looking for a script engine for game developing. I dont like lua (because of it's syntax and features), Im very like js, so I want to use google V8, but seems it is not very friendly in iOS? So, Is there a c++ bind can cross v8 and JavaScriptCore? In iOS use JavaScriptCore and  others use V8 to bind the same C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there is **no** such bind library. When I worked in game dev company in the past year, we created our own bind. But it is proprietary code. We used JavascriptCore on iOS and V8 for Android.
So it's possible, but to my regret I can't help you with code.

Answer (score 2):

I've started a project for this.  It currently supports building and running the examples included in version 3.14 of the V8 project, as well as Node version 0.10.

https://github.com/flyover/v8like

I've also made a fork of the Node project with project files for iOS and OS X including targets for compiling against V8 using the simulator (define USE_SIMULATOR) and the v8like project.

https://github.com/flyover/node